# regex encapsulation

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've got a question concerning regex.

I was wondering how one could replace an encapsulated text, something like `{key:23}` to something like `<span class="highlightable">23</span`, so that the entity will still remain encapsulated, but with something else.

I will do this in JS, but the regex is what is important, I have been searching for a while, probably searching for the wrong terms, I should probably learn more about regex, generally.

In any case, is there someone who knows how to perform this operation with simplicity?

Thanks!

Comment: So you just want to put `23` in a span?

Comment: learn regex, do it your own, post here after trying as hard as you can. programmers can write code when searching for existing solutions fail, not ask for someone else to write it.

Comment: Is there any relationships between the word 'key' and classname?

Comment: @LeleDumbo I thought maybe others wanted to know as well, and as this is a great hinder in my current task, I thought maybe someone could help me out, turns out I was right.

Comment: @Dolphin_Wood No, sorry for the confusion, just an example class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are new to regex. You need to learn more about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

The regex is somewhat basic in your case if you do not need any nested encapsulated text support.

Let's start:

1. The beginning is `{key:` - it will match the substring literally. Note that `{` can be a special character (denoting start of a limiting quantifier), thus, it is a good idea to escape it: `{key:`.
2. `([^}]+)` - This is a bit more interesting: the round brackets around are a capturing group that let us later back-reference the matched text. The `[^}]+` means *1  or more characters (due to `+`) other than `}`* (as `[^}]` is a negated character class where `^` means *not*)
3. `}` matches a `}` literally.
4. In the replacement string, we'll get the captured text using a backreference `$1`.

So, the entire regex will look like:

```
{key:([^}]+)}
```

See [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pE7bR6/2)

Code snippet:

```js
var re = /{key:([^}]+)}/g; 
var str = '{key:23}';
var subst = '<span class="highlightable">$1</span>'; 
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = str.replace(re, subst);
```

```css
.highlightable
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

If you want to use a different behavior based on the value of `key`, then you'll need to adjust the regex to either match digits only (with `\d+`) or letters only (say, with `[a-zA-Z]` for English), or other [shorthand classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html), ranges (= character classes), or their combinations.

Comment: Thanks man, great answer ... I'll be sure to look into the depth of regex once my task is finished.

Comment: Good answer.  One comment.  I get your point about how you like to escape the opening brace even if it's not in a context where there is any ambiguity.  That's a matter of style so I have no opinion about that.  However, you never have to escape the closing brace.  It's never in a position where it could be a literal or closing brace to a quantifier.  There is never ambiguity about its context. To me, seeing a character escaped willy-nilly causes confusion because I wonder if it's a metacharacter sequence I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Luv2code: You are right. I think I meant consistency (if opening brace is escaped, I'd escape the closing one), but it is just my style. Closing brace really does not have to be escaped, point 3 is updated.

Answer (score 1):

It's important that you find {key:23} in your text first, and then replace it with your wanted syntax, this way you avoid replacing {key:'sometext'} with that syntax which is unwanted.

```
var str = "some random text {key:23} some random text {key:name}"; 
var n = str.replace(/\{key:[\d]+\}/gi, function myFunction(x){return x.replace(/\{key:/,'<span>').replace(/\}/, '</span>');});
```

this way only {key:AnyNumber} gets replaced, and {key:AnyThingOtherThanNumbers} don't get touched.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is in var a, then:

```
var test = a.replace( /\{key:(\d+)\}/g, "<span class='highlightable'>$1</span>");
```